# parsed html, changed to numbers and possibly through piping (R) but keep getting wrong number

Tags: r, string, rvest, tibble

I am trying to change character number(in character data type) --> numeric number by typing the following code;

```
  > my.numbers<-c("10B","1M","1000","130T")
    > step.one<-my.numbers[grep("B|M|T",my.numbers,value=F)]
    > step.two<-gsub("B",1000000000,step.one)
    > step.two<-gsub("M",1000000,step.two) 
    > step.two<-gsub("T",1000000000000,step.two)
    > my.numbers[grep("B|M|T",my.numbers,value=F)]<-step.two
    > my.numbers
    [1] "101e+09"  "11e+06"   "1000"     "1301e+12"
```

it works, so i don't have issue here but I tried to make it "nicer" by piping;

```
   > my.numbers<-c("10B","1M","1000","130T")
    > my.numbers[grep("B|M|T",my.numbers,value=F)]<-gsub("B",1000000000,my.numbers) %>% gsub("M",1000000,) %>% gsub("T",1000000000000,)
    Warning message:
    In gsub(., "M", 1e+06, ) :
      argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
    > my.numbers
    [1] "1e+12" "1e+12" "1000"  "1e+12"
```

the number seems to change drastically. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.` to refer to the value from previous pipe and pass it in `gsub` :

```
library(magrittr)

my.numbers<-c("10B","1M","1000","130T")

my.numbers <- gsub("B",1000000000,my.numbers) %>% 
  gsub("M",1000000, .) %>% 
  gsub("T",1000000000000, .)

my.numbers

#[1] "101e+09"  "11e+06"   "1000"     "1301e+12"
```

Comment: Thanks. just out of curiosity, if you use gsub does R automatically does arithmetic calculation even though the data type inside the vectors are strings? bit confused here.

Comment: Those numbers are turned into strings as you can see quotes (`""`) around them. To convert them to numbers use `as.numeric(my.numbers)`.